# Conditions for inequality to hold

Tags: calculus

Suppose $ h_1, q_1, h_P, P $ are positive constants, $ x, y > 0,\ D(u) $ is a continuous and non-negative function, $ 0 < \phi < 1 $, and $ P > D(u) $ for all $ u \in [x,y] $. Under what conditions or what conditions can we impose on the constants and the function $ D(u) $ (convex?) so that the
following inequality hold?
\begin{equation} 
  (h_1 q_1 - h_P)  \int_x^y D(u) du
  \geq 4 P (\phi + 1)^2 \ h_P \cdot y
\end{equation}

(I am trying to force this inequality so that the condition of a theorem is met)